# Should I include the Google Map script tag on every page of my website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

It seems that if I do not include the script tag for the google map on each page of my website, then I get this error: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"`.

If I do include the script tag on a page where there is no map I get this error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null"`.

Maybe I need some sort of check system in the javascript to see if that ID exists? I wasn't sure what is the correct way of incorporating the Google map API?

This is what my javascript looks like:
// Google Map

```
    function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Include it on every page that you intend to use a map.
- Don't include it elsewhere.
- Fix your JavaScript to not do things that do not need to be done.  If you don't intend to render a map, don't write code that renders a map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think about what your own scripts are doing...If you include scripts which reference google maps on every page of your site the you will get that error on pages that do not have the library loaded..

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just ended up moving the map code from my script file into the html file for the map page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have map on each page then you can include script on each pach